# combobox in a toolbar in an AUI Frame in mac os x

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I added a `combobox` in a `toolbar` in an AUI frame modifying the AUI demo in the wxPython demo:

```
AUI_DockingWindowMgr.py
```

In `__init__`, I added the combobox:

```
    tb3.AddControl(
                wx.ComboBox(
                    tb3, 2342, "", choices=["", "This", "is a", "wx.ComboBox"],
                    size=(150,-1), style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN
                ))
```

In mac os x, the combobox doesn't show up. Running the file in Linux and Windows shows the combobox.

What should I add in the code to show the combobox in mac os x?

Comment: Could you double check the indentation?

Comment: Everything on one line doesn't help. The original indentation comes from the ToolBar.py demo

Comment: I uploaded the complete code on [codepad](http://codepad.org/QrjoJhOu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Hide and Show on the controler.

`combobox = wx.ComboBox(
    tb3, 2342, "", choices=["", "This", "is a", "wx.ComboBox"],
    size=(150,-1), style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN
    )
tb3.AddControl(combobox)
tb3.Realize()
combobox.Hide()
combobox.Show()`

Related ticket:
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/4575